# Confusing choice- born or borne

Tags: word-choice

having a good day.
[image]
Mary has BORNE a son(give birth to...)
Does this book lie to me?

Comment: Hey Vmir, welcome to ELL! It's usually best to transcribe what's in a book, rather than photograph it. Text in a photograph can't be indexed, nor can it be read by screen reader software for people who can't see well. It would be helpful if you put typed in the text rather than posting a photo.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that you don't have the 'e' when the thing being given birth to is the subject of the verb as an intransitive. The 'e' is usually used, in my experience, in the case where the mother is the subject. Authorities vary a little as to whether the 'e' should be present in other cases, but there is a clear preponderance towards including the 'e' if there's no birth involved. In actual usage by native speakers (writers?) there's a little more variety, and most people aren't likely to notice if you get it 'wrong', but teachers will tend to.

So it is right that "Mary has **borne** a son". Where it is arguably *wrong* is to suggest that it's right to say "Marshall has **born** his sorrows bravely". That *should* be ***borne*** as well. But a lot of native speakers will get that 'wrong' as well.

Comment: Are you sure which “weather” or “whether” you have used?

Comment: @SolarMike: Well, that's embarrassing. I've been mixing homophones a lot lately. I wonder if I'm typing more with the auditory past of my brain or something...

Comment: Since the latter part of the 18th century, a distinction has been made between born and borne as past participles of the verb bear 1 . Borne is the past participle in all senses that do not refer to physical birth (unless followed by 'by'): the wheatfields have borne abundantly this year. the burden of the department's workload was borne by only two people. I was born in 1952; I was born to my mother (and father), but I was borne by my mother in 1952. She bore me in that year.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: yes, I inadvertently suggested there's a balance between authorities, where there is a clear (but seemingly not universal) preponderance, and it's not what the book says. I've updated to clarify/fix.